# scikit-image skiimagu.filters import *

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm and doing:

```
from skimage.filters import *
```

It is giving me following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'denoise_tv_chambolle'

Can someone help me with the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from skimage.restoration import *
```

It's not the `filters` package it's `restoration` packge.  See [this the documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html).  You seem to have mistaken which package you should use.

---

Note that `*` is bad practice because it may conflict with other functions in your script.